# Make Slider arrow always visible in magic slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

iam using magic slider for my website

http://m2.alothemes.com/bencher/

Here i want to make my arrow always visible . so i write the following css code

```
.slick-next.slick-arrow, .slick-prev.slick-arrow{

    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #eeeeee73 !important;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

This code is working . But the problm is that when i hover it then arrow is not showing and one effect is coming . Please try to fix this .

I want my slider arrow always present with a background color . Currently it is visble only when we hover the slider .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add below css will help you to get the desire output.

```
.home-slider.home-slider-index .slick-arrow {
    OPACITY: 1;
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

[image: Arrow]

Comment: nice explained with screenshot (and using browser developer tool)

Comment: thank you for this code . But when i hover this arrow then arrow is going to edges of the page and it despair  . Cloud you please check why this happen . The css in hover making problem .

Comment: not able inspect properly but there is css for hover which you have to remove for .home-slider-index:hover .slick-arrow. remove those and will work fine. Do accept & upvote if this helpful.

Comment: yes friend , but i am loking for to stop the hover effect . even the code you give and my code is same . you just made !important . up voted already

Answer (score 0):

You have this rules at (index) (in-page css?):

```
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
   color: #707070;
   background-color: #4f0606;
   border-color: #ffffff;
}
```

that overwrite the rule you wrote. In order to solve this, you can add `!important` next to the properties you want to overwrite, or consider to reorganize the import of your CSS files

Answer (score 0):

Add this class to your slider arrow.

`.staticArrow{
opacity: 1 !important;
visibility: visible !important;
}`